# Make Emacs 28 tab-line-tab-modified styling sensitive to whether tab is active or not

Tags: tabbar, customize-face

Emacs 28 added the `tab-line-tab-modified` face to enable (for example) bolding the text of any tab corresponding to a modified buffer. I style my active tab differently from inactive tabs; my face definitions look like this:

```
(set-face-attribute 'tab-line-tab-current nil ;; active tab in current window
  :background "SkyBlue1" :foreground "black" :height 140 :box nil)
(set-face-attribute 'tab-line-tab-inactive nil ;; inactive tab
  :background "LightCyan1" :foreground "black" :height 130 :box nil)
```

So I can add

```
(set-face-attribute 'tab-line-tab-modified nil ;; active tab in current window
  :background "SkyBlue1" :foreground "black" :height 140 :weight 'bold :box nil)
```

but that results in any modified tab having the `SkyBlue1` background and larger size regardless of whether it's the active tab or not. I'm pretty much a Lisp-newbie, but can anyone tell me how to modify the face attribute, presumably using a function that examines the tab, to set those properties appropriately? Or to use the function to inherit from one of the other faces and then just set the `weight`. (This is on MacOS, using homebrew, but I can't imagine that matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding background and foreground in `tab-line-tab-modified` you could just disable inheritance of these face attributes by using something like:

```elisp
(set-face-attribute 'tab-line-tab-modified nil
 :inherit nil :height 140 :weight 'bold :box nil)
```

Comment: Oh. That works great! Can't believe I didn't figure that out. Thanks.